# Lua Insert table to table

Tags: lua, lua-table

Basic table, how they should be. But me need do it by function, how i can do that?

```lua
local mainMenu = {
  caption = "Main Window",
  description = "test window",
  buttons = {
  { id = 1, value = "Info" },
  { id = 2, value = "Return" },
  { id = 3, value = "Ok" },
  { id = 4, value = "Cancel" }
  },
  popup = true
  }
```

Table should be based on outside params, and code one table for each variable of options - not better way. I make a function for that, they should create basic options like caption or description and pop up, and insert values to buttons table (if option enabled - add button). But here the problem, they wont insert to tmp table, buttons table and their values for next options.

```lua
   function createMenu()
    tmp = {}
    --buttons insert
   if(config.info) then
    table.insert(tmp, {buttons = {id = 1, value = "Info"}});
   elseif(config.return) then
    table.insert(tmp, {buttons = {id = 2, value = "Return"}});
   end
    --table main
   table.insert(tmp, {
    caption = "Main Window",
    description = "test window",
    popup = true
    })
     return tmp
   end
```

How i can fixing them?

Comment: `config.return` isn't valid because `return` is a lua keyword. Try `config["return"]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From looking at your `createMenu` function, two obvious problems stick out:

1. assigning to *global* `tmp` a new table every time `createMenu` is
   called.
2. using the `return` keyword as a key in `config`.

One can be a problem if you use `tmp` somewhere else in your code outside the `createMenu` function. The obvious fix is to change it to:

```
local tmp = {}
```

For the second problem, you *can* use a lua keyword as a table key if you really want but you won't be able to use the `.` dot syntax to access this since Lua will parse this the wrong way. Instead, you need to change:

```
config.return
```

to

```
config["return"].
```

**Edit**: After reading your comment and checking the example table, it looks like only the button table is accessed by numerical index. In that case, you'll want to use `table.insert` only on `button`. If you want to create the table to have associative keys then you'll have to do something like this:

```
function createMenu()
  local tmp = 
  {
    --table main
    caption = "Main Window",
    description = "test window",
    popup = true,
    --button table
    buttons = {}
  }
  --buttons insert
  if config.info then
    table.insert(tmp.buttons, {id = 1, value = "Info"});
  elseif config['return']  then
    table.insert(tmp.buttons, {id = 2, value = "Return"});
  end

  return tmp
end
```

This will produce the `mainMenu` table you're describing in your question.

Comment: yes, you right, but top table - only for example. So createMenu function should create table, and usage window = createMenu() and send window by function - doCreateWindow(window, param1, callback). CreateMenu - return table. And here the problem - insert to tmp table - buttons table and their values based on options/outside data (problems with insert, becouse table.insert(tmp, {buttons[2] = {id = 4, value = "Text"}}) does not work for me )

Comment: @HappyDay You'll have to better clarify the problem you're having. What is the expected output after calling `createMenu`? What do you expect the table returned to look like? What do you actually get instead?

Comment: So, problems only with table.insert, i cant insert values to table - buttons inside table tmp =(

Comment: `table.insert` works with the index part of the table only. In other words, after doing `table.insert`, your button table will be at `tmp[1]`, `tmp[2]` etc.. Use the dot syntax or `[]` syntax to insert by associative key.

Comment: so, i can use that function? table.insert(tmp.buttons, {id = 1, value = "text"}), and they will work?

Comment: Tested, application crushed by lua -  Error module name:lua5.1.dll. They looks a right way, but something wrong here, becouse lua5.1.dll crushed here.

Comment: @HappyDay that definitely should not be happening if you're using the lua interpreter to test the script. Lua's a safe language, any script errors will give a stacktrack of the problem -- not crash with a core dump from a dll. Are you embedding Lua in another host application?

Comment: yep, that my game. So, i debug that by string to table, and they return to me that string = {description='test window',caption='Main Window',{id=1,value='Info',},popup=true,} -- but in options, i am enable 2 options for return and info.

Comment: @HappyDay Note your using nested if's in your `createMenu` function so at most only one of the options will be in. You'll have to un-nest them to allow more than one button option.